# Dropdownlist selected value not changing to selected index zero after exporting data to file

Tags: asp.net

I am using one dropdownlist for exporting file. I want here once user select any of the fileformat in dropdownlist after exporting file again dropdownlist selectedindex should change it to zero like initial state. For that i have tried to use this code:

```
if(ddl.SelectedIndex > 0)ddl.SelectedIndex=0;
```

But as i assumed due to download file code response.Clear and response.End dropdownlist selected index is not setting to zero.
Need help.

Comment: Use javascript to reset the DropDownList. It's not gonna work in code behind since the UI does not get updated when sending a file.

Comment: @VDWWD I am calling javascript method from Ispostback method and in javascript method i am setting dropdownlist selected index to zero, But after that it is not hitting dropdown selected index changed event. And if i am calling javascript method under selectedindexchanged event then javascript method is not getting called.

Comment: Dont call from ispostback, that is the same problem as your question. Use a click on the button that starts the export.

Comment: Ispostback event i used to just check the behaviour of the page. And i am not using any button click instead of dropdownselectedindexchanged event to export.